# Can a web browser control be embeded in a Metro XAML App with the full features of a Metro Web App?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Can you embed a IE web browser control in a C# XAML based Metro app on windows 8?
Also when doing so can the HTML/Javascript it it have the full featureset that a Windows 8 HTML app has,such as calling the WinRT apis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a WebView control you can use to view websites or open html strings, but I believe to be able to communicate with the WinRT APIs you would need to relay the calls through the [ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx) events.